# if conditionals for quiz

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am working on a quiz which, depending on the answer given, should return a string (up, down or medium) which I add after that in a className in my component to show the correct icon.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in this logic ? Both arguments (answer and id) are getting fine to this point and I can read them. But the if statements just ignore them and it jumps to the else statement directly (which always gives "down").

This is the logic I wrote:

```
export const checkAnswer = (answer, id) => {
if ((answer === 'Nein') && (id === '0' || id === '3' || id === '5')) {
  return 'up';
} else if ((answer === 'Ja') && (id === '1' || id === '2' || id === '4' || id === '6')){
  return 'up';
} else if (answer === 'Weiß nicht') {
  return 'medium';
} else {
  return 'down';
}
```

I appreciate anyones help.

Thanks for your help, guys. Here is furthermore the code where I am passing the arguments:

```
questions.map(question => {
    if (checkAnswer(question.answer, question.id) === 'up') {
      correctAnswers += 1;
      debugger
    }
    if (
      (question.category === 'Effektivkosten' || 'Rentenfaktor') &&
      question.answer === 'Nein'
    ) {
      correctAnswers += 2;
    }

    if (question.winner && question.answer === 'Ja') {
      winnerAnswer = true;
    }
  });
```

And here is how all the questions are structured:

```
{
    id: 0,
    category: 'Effektivkosten',
    text: 'Sind die Effektivkosten höher als 1,5%?',
    shortText: 'Über 1,5% p.A.',
    answer: '',
    options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Ja'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Nein'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Weiß nicht'
      }
    ]
  },
```

And here the table where I read the "string" and add it to the className:

```
 <table>
                  <tbody>
                    {questions.map((question, index) => (
                      <tr key={question.id}>
                        <td className="name">
                          <strong>{question.category}:</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td className="shortName">{question.shortText}</td>
                        <td>
                          <i
                            className={`icon-thumb icon-thumb__${checkAnswer(
                              question.answer,
                              question.id
                            )}`}
                          />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Please, show an example of how you call it (i.e. what parameters you're actually passing). Because the code in itself seems ok.

Comment: Maybe you're passing the `id` as integer and you're strictly checking it matches a string ( 5 vs '5' )

Comment: the `console.log(checkAnswer('Nein','0'));` returns `'up'`

Comment: Hi Kamil, it should, but it actually does not. Any idea why that can be?

Comment: 10 points Drago!! Thank you very much. Indeed, I was passing integers and trying to receive strings. It works!!! Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're using strict comparison to check whether the id is `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, but your ids are actually numbers (as per the question structure you posted).

With strict comparison, if your inputs are numbers you have to compare them with numbers, not strings.

That is

```
export const checkAnswer = (answer, id) => {
if ((answer === 'Nein') && (id === 0 || id === 3 || id === 5)) {
  return 'up';
} else if ((answer === 'Ja') && (id === 1 || id === 2 || id === 4 || id === 6)){
  return 'up';
} else if (answer === 'Weiß nicht') {
  return 'medium';
} else {
  return 'down';
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot for your help#

Answer (score 0):

I would use includes to check for multiple ID's

```
export const checkAnswer = (answer, id) => {
if ((answer === 'Nein') && ([0,3,5].includes(id))) {
   return 'up';
} else if ((answer === 'Ja') && ( [1,2,4,6].includes(id) )){
  return 'up';
} else if (answer === 'Weiß nicht') {
  return 'medium';
} else {
  return 'down';
}
```

you can also use  [1,2,4,6].includes(parseInt(id)) to overcome typechecking

Comment: Thanks Federico, that was right!! Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're passing the id as integer and you're strictly checking it matches a string ( 5 vs '5' ) – Dragoş Paul Marinescu 16 mins ago